# Can I create an Ubuntu One account without downloading Ubuntu One?

Tags: thunderbird, filelink

I would like to use Ubuntu One with Thunderbird Filelink.

Is it possible to create an Ubuntu One account without downloading the Ubuntu One software?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Ubuntu One account at https://one.ubuntu.com